# jQuery infinite loop, animate many items?

Tags: javascript, jquery

First of all, here's a jFiddle which will help you see where I'm coming from: http://jsfiddle.net/gfyans/x9fGS/ (this is very rough, and it's 4am, so it's not the greatest code in the world).

Basically what I want to do is create a bunch of divs in my document and animate the opacity of each one at the same time.

I have it creating the grid and animating one after the other, but I'm stuck at concurrent animations. I take it setInterval isn't the right thing to use for what I want?

Thanks,
Greg.

Comment: Your function just picks one random box and animates it. If you want to animate them all, you should loop over all of them instead of just picking one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set only one interval in which trigger the event to all the boxes.
Like in this snippet:

```
var boxes$ = $('.boxItem');

// Triggers the event for all the boxes
function forceAnimate() {
    boxes$.trigger('box.animate');
}

setInterval(forceAnimate, interval);
```

Here is a [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/WrSqS/), hope it helps.

Comment: I never even thought to use a custom event. Thank you!